# how to load csv file in flutter?

Tags: csv, flutter

I want to use a csv file in my flutter app, but I have an exception. How to solve it please?

```
my data.csv 

id,symbol,open,high,low,close,volume,exchange,timestamp,date,update_date_time
33668191,C,16.2,16.3042,16.2,16.3042,477600,NYSE,221115600,1977-01-03,8/26/2013 19:35:35
33668192,C,16.3042,16.3542,16.25,16.3542,340800,NYSE,221202000,1977-01-04,8/26/2013 19:35:35
33668670,C,15.3667,15.5208,15.3667,15.4708,76800,NYSE,280731600,1978-11-24,8/26/2013 19:35:36
```

I added assets in my pubspec.yaml

assets:
  - asset/thesaurusEn.csv
  - asset/data.csv

```
List<List<dynamic>> data =[];

loadAsset() async{

  final myData = await  rootBundle.loadString('asset/data.csv');
  print(myData);

}
```

> Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset:
>   asset/data.csv)

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986359/flutter-how-to-read-data-from-simple-spreadsheet

Comment: no not the same i want to load csv file with rootBundle

Comment: doesn't the answer in that link use rootBundle?

Comment: what dose mean my error and how to solve it

Comment: no not the answer

Comment: there is missing space here - asset/thesaurusEn.csv it should be two spaces and not just one

Comment: no there is no missing space ,bcz when i save it it give me no error

Comment: just when i copie it it look like that

Comment: no, it won't because it's a dart code it's in your pubspect.yaml

Comment: check out this example
https://gist.github.com/Rahiche/4c74680b0d944511f8b8e5622ec21154

Comment: thank you but i still have the same error :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `import 'package:csv/csv.dart';` 
Inside you have a method called `CsvToListConverter()`, using this you can convert your CSV data to a nice list.

```
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
...
List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(data);
```

Data will be in `[[],[],[],[]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working. I've checked it and it's working fine.

Here is the output:

[image]

I've tried to replicate your issue and it needs to do something with the naming convention of your "**asset**" folder, the declaration of `asset/` in the ***pubspec.yaml*** file, and lastly in your code `final myData = await  rootBundle.loadString('asset/data.csv');`

If you have misspelled in either one of those, here's what will happen.

**Scenario 1:**

Folder created is "assets"

> pubspec.yaml
>
> ```
> assets:
>  - assets/
> ```

> main.dart
>
> ```
> final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("asset/data.csv");
> ```

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

Folder created is "assets"

> pubspec.yaml
>
> ```
> assets:
>  - asset/
> ```

> main.dart
>
> ```
> final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.csv");
> ```

The moment you've save your ***pubspec.yaml***, you will get an error like this:

[image]

But this is still executable, if you run the app this is the output:

[image]

**Scenario 3:**

Folder created is "asset"

> pubspec.yaml
>
> ```
> assets:
>  - assets/
> ```

> main.dart
>
> ```
> final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.csv");
> ```

Same error with Scenario 1 and 2:

[image]

Since you got an error:

> Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset:
> asset/data.csv)

Check your folder, and pubspec.yaml if it is all named correctly ("asset").

I suggest making it all to "**assets**" as it was defined in the examples in [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

Answer (score 1):

Something simple to try is to **Stop** the app entirely on your IDE and then **Run** it again instead of using Hot Restart/Reload. I was unable to load my CSV file until I did that. Woops!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load your data in the `main()` function, **before** you call `runApp()`?

In that case make sure you call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before you try to read the data.

Here's an example:

```dart
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // <---- Crucial
    final csvData = await readCsvData();
    runApp(MyApp(csvData));
}
```