# No such file when reading CSV file in Flutter

Tags: csv, flutter, dart

I am trying to read a `csv` file in flutter and I am getting an error

```
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

The csv file has been declared in assets section in `pubspec.yaml`

And the path to the file is correct, here is my attempt to read the file synchronously:

-- at the begining of the class:

```
List<String> lines;
```

-- pubspec.yaml, assets section:

```
assets:
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/data/data.csv
```

-- Method to read file

```
void _readDataFile(String csvFile) {
    File file = File(csvFile);
    lines = file.readAsLinesSync();
  }
```

-- Calling the above method ---

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //other stuff ...
    // ...
    // ...

    _readDataFile("assets/data/data.csv");
  }
```

Comment: try  `_readDataFile("~/data/data.csv")` also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020537/4712391

Answer (score 1):

You can use rootBundle to get the file in asset:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/data.csv');
}
```

official document link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets 
similar question [Flutter - Read text file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets)

Comment: thanks, i think though, your answer refers to asynchronous read waiting for a Future, while my question talks about a synchronous read, but its a good starting point, thanks!